# Compact embedding in Bochner space

Tags: functional-analysis, bochner-spaces

Let $V \subset H$ be a compact embedding of Hilbert spaces. Suppose $u_n$ is bounded uniformly in $L^2(0,T;V)$. Does it follow that (for a subsequence), $u_{n_j}(t) \to u(t)$ in $H$ for some $u(t) \in H$?

Comment: Do you mean $u_{n_j}(t)\to u(t)$ in $H$ for a.e. $t\in (0,T)$?

Comment: @MaoWao yes that's right

Comment: Then the answer is no even for scalar-valued functions (which correspond to the compact embedding $\mathbb{K}\subset\mathbb{K}$), as is explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863205/does-weak-convergence-in-l2-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-along-subse