# Do weak convergence or strong convergence in every $L^p$ imply almost-everywhere convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n,f\in C(\mathbb R^d)\cap L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ be positive functions such that
$$ \int_\mathbb{R^d} f_n(x)\,dx \,=\, \int_\mathbb{R^d} f(x)\,dx$$
and either:

1. for every $\phi\in C_c(\mathbb R^d)$

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \phi(x)\,f_n(x)\,dx \,=\, \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \phi(x)\,f(x)\,dx\;;$$

or:

2. for every $K$ compact subset of $\mathbb R^d$, every $p\geq1$
   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_K |f_n(x)-f(x)|^p\,d x \,=\, 0\;.$$

In case 1. can I conclude that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb R^d$ ? What about case 2. ?

If not, for sure in case 2. almost-everywhere convergence holds true along a subsequence. Is this true also in case 1.?

Comment: For 1: see the counterexample in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863205/does-weak-convergence-in-l2-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-along-subse?rq=1

Comment: @daw: The restriction by the OP that the functions in question are non-negative and have suitable integral is a quite strong condition not present in your linked question.

Comment: 1) is not true, even for a subsequence. As a counterexample, try $f_n(x)=1_{[-1,1]}(x)\cdot (1-\sin(2\pi n x))$ and $f(x)=1_{[-1,1]}(x)$.

Comment: Is dx shorthand notation for integration w.r.t the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Jacobiman yes it is