# Weak* convergence on $L^\infty(\Omega)$ and almost everywhere convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence, weak-topology

Let $\Omega$ be finite measure space. Suppose that $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ for the weak* topology.

Does there exists a subsequence (or a subnet) $(f_{n_k})$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost everywhere?

Same question with the additional assumption $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty} \leq C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: You will have to dig a little, but I'm sure this question has been answered before on this site. The standard counterexample is $f_n(x)=e^{inx}$ on $L^2([0,2\pi])$, for which weak$^\ast$ convergence follows from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863205/does-weak-convergence-in-l2-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-along-subse

Comment: the sequence in that example converges weak-star in $L^\infty$ (the proof is the same as in the $L^2$ case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Does weak convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence almost everywhere along subsequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863205/does-weak-convergence-in-l2-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-along-subse)